# NUL delimited variable

Tags: bash, command-substitution

GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Idea is to set a variable to a NUL delimited data set. Here `$samples`

This, however, result in:

> warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

when doing:

```
samples="$(find . -type d -iregex './sample[0-9][0-9]' -printf "%f\0" | sort -z)"
```

Thought I could re-use this variable as I need to iterate the same values multiple times:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' sample; do
    echo $sample
done<<< "$samples"
```

I could use `\n` over `\0` in the *find* command in this exact case, but would like to know how, if possible, to do it with NUL delimiter generally speaking.

Optionally I could do:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' sample; do
    echo $sample
done< <(find . -type d -iregex './E[0-9][0-9]' -printf "%f\0" | sort -z)
```

but - as I need to loop it several times it makes for some very redundant code - and would have to run the *find* and *sort* command each time.

Convert the result into an array perhaps?

---

- Is this possible?
- Why can not NUL delimited data be used as is?

Comment: See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) where several approaches are given to loop over `find`'s output reliably.

Comment: Why are you sorting the filenames? They would be sorted lexicographically anyway.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Not in result from find. The inode table (or Directory Entries is perhaps more correct) is not sorted. No idea how find is implemented, but if it uses `readdir`, *it is unlikely the names will be sorted in any fashion*, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html#NOTES and https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Directory_Entries so perhaps in some hash order. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTree

Comment: @user3342816 Ah, yes. Your are absolutely correct. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a fact that you can't store `\0` null bytes in a bash string context, because of the underlying C implementation. See [Why $'\0' or $'\x0' is an empty string? Should be the null-character, isn't it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19229243/5291015).

One option would be strip off the null bytes after the sort command, at the end of the pipeline using `tr` and store the result to solve the immediate problem of the warning message thrown. But that would still leave your logic flawed as the filenames with newlines would still be broken.

Use an array, use the `mapfile` or `readarray` command (on bash 4.4+) to directly slurp in the results from the `find` command

```
IFS= readarray -t -d '' samples < <(find . -type d -iregex './sample[0-9][0-9]' -printf "%f\0" | sort -z)
```

Comment: Thank you. But would it not then be the same as using `-printf "%f\n"`? If one are separating with newline in the result one are assuming there are no newlines in the data anyway (if you get what I mean). The whole point of using zero delimiter is to be sure one do not split names with newlines in them …

Comment: @user3342816: I thought your intention was to run the `find` command once, so after sorting the results, you wouldn't need the null delimited output anymore, so store the result in the variable without it

Comment: From the link you posted (tried to find something like that first) I read it as it is not possible to store zero in a var, so that much set array to be the "only" option.

Comment: Yes. That was the intention. But if a value can have new-line, the result would be ambiguous even if sorted correctly.

Comment: @user3342816 : Then I suppose the readarray option is the one you want

Comment: As Q/A stands now I think if you remove everything between the link and the array paragraph it should be OK to mark as solved - if I'm not missing anything. Or I could delete Q all together if it is OK with you?

Comment: @user3342816 I’ll leave it up to you to keep or delete the question but I’ve modified the answer

Answer (score 6):

The `bash` shell does not support what you want to do.  The `zsh` shell does out of the box.

```
% mkdir sample11 SAMple12 sample21 sample22 dir1
% ll
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 fpm fpm 4096 Jun  9 13:46 dir1
drwxrwxr-x 2 fpm fpm 4096 Jun  9 13:46 sample11
drwxrwxr-x 2 fpm fpm 4096 Jun  9 13:46 SAMple12
drwxrwxr-x 2 fpm fpm 4096 Jun  9 13:46 sample21
drwxrwxr-x 2 fpm fpm 4096 Jun  9 13:46 sample22
% samples=$(find . -type d -iregex './sample[0-9][0-9]' -print0 | sort -z)
% echo $samples
./sample11./SAMple12./sample21./sample22
% echo $samples | od -a
0000000   .   /   s   a   m   p   l   e   1   1 nul   .   /   S   A   M
0000020   p   l   e   1   2 nul   .   /   s   a   m   p   l   e   2   1
0000040 nul   .   /   s   a   m   p   l   e   2   2 nul  nl
0000055
%
```

Comment: ... however, please beware that the value of the environment variable `samples` will be truncated at the `nul` byte when being passed to child processes: If you perform `export samples` and start a child instance of `zsh`, `$samples` will only be `./sample11` in the child instance.